# ListView selecting multiple choices

Tags: android

When I click a list item, every 12th item is also selected. No idea why?

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) v;

    if (check.isChecked()){
        check.setChecked(false);
        selections.remove((Integer) position);
    }
    else{
        check.setChecked(true);
        selections.add((Integer) position);
    }
}
```

I use an ArrayAdapter. Names is a String[] of about 1000 options.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, names);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: post your adapter definition here. I think the problem is there

Comment: Android recycles views in a `ListView` so if you click on your 1st `CheckBox` and scroll that view will be used after some time again and the `CheckBox` already will be checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is in Your adapter's getView method.

If u reuse object's there, then You have to refresh selection of CheckedTextView every time

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this in your adapter's constructor, set the status of checkbox to false at start

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
        }
```

then change it to true whenever it is clicked.And change the state of checkbox accordingly.